# ArcMap field mapping with Garmin GPS, Connectivity Issue

Tags: arcmap, gps, garmin

We are planning to go on the field for field mapping.

We have Garmin GPS devices and planned to make a connection with the ArcMap GPS toolbar.

Unfortunately, ArcMap can only communicate with the GPS through a COM Port. And the newer laptops do not have COM Ports.

So, we are stuck on how to proceed? We are planning to set up virtual COM Ports but I would like to know if there is a better way of achieving it?

I did found out a few suggested questions that are way too old. [GPS - Garmin 60CSX connectivity issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12096/gps-garmin-60csx-connectivity-issue), and [Connecting Garmin GPS Device to ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165762/connecting-garmin-gps-device-to-arcmap)

I am sharing a few screenshots for better interpretation:-

**Garmin GPSMAP 66st**

[image]

**Error**

> Unable to detect GPS device on COM ports supported by the hardware.
> Make sure your GPS is turned on, connected properly, and sending data.
> Also, review the Baud rate, Stop bits, Data bits, Parity settings for
> the port on this dialog.

[image: Error]

**Device Manager (Show hidden items enabled)**[image]

**ArcMap documentaion**[image]

Comment: Please provide error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to searches and easily read on all devices.

Comment: What is the Garmin Device Model?

Comment: Are you using USB or Bluetooth?

Comment: I will gather this information as soon as possible :)

Comment: Hello @Mapperz, the device model is Garmin GPSMAP 66st(screenshot added in the question), and, yes the device has Bluetooth support. I have tried to connect the device to my computer via Bluetooth, but have been unsuccessful. Thank you!!

Comment: you will require the garmin express software to link the GPS unit see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ik6-NMSa_0E  (or you can link to a smartphone that will link to windows via Bluetooth.)

Comment: Hello @Mapperz, we checked the Garmin Express Software and installed it, now the GPS is connected to Laptops, but the primary mission to get it connected to ArcMap is still not accomplished. Thank you!!

Comment: you will need to adjust the settings for ArcMap - Serial Port SPP Slave on com ports ports 3, 6 or 7. See "Stage 3 0 Fieldwork, Track Logging and Cultural Data 
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Simon_Johnson/publication/256000773_TIPS_AND_TRICKS_FOR_MAP_COMPILATION_USING_ArcGIS_SOFTWARE_AND_TABLET_PCs/links/00b4952160767e4c7a000000/TIPS-AND-TRICKS-FOR-MAP-COMPILATION-USING-ArcGIS-SOFTWARE-AND-TABLET-PCs.pdf

Comment: @Mapperz, thank you so much for this info, I will test this and update you :)

Comment: @Mapperz, here is an update, so we managed to have the virtual COM Ports detected in ArcMap GPS ToolBar, and had the GPS Unit connected via a USB, now the next challenge is how should the COM Ports get assigned to the USB Ports for them to show in GPS toolbar, as of now it just shows COM Ports in the toolbar?

Comment: @YogeshChavan try https://www.gpssensordrivers.com/ and test you can get data from the usb port and create/re-direct to a virtual com port.

Comment: @Mapperz, Thank you, will test this:)

Comment: @Mapperz, We were finally able to connect the GPSMAP with ArcGIS Pro 2.7, Pro 2.7 is included with this functionality to connect to a GNSS Device. Thank you for backing me up with these support docs:)

Answer (score 2):

I question why you need to hook up a GPS to desktop ArcMap.

Such an approach is archaic and was really the first attempts for mobile mapping before the rise and popularity of tablets and the ever more powerful mobile phones. I would consider the GPS toolbar legacy functionality, there is not even an equivalent to it in ArcGIS Pro. *Update - Since version 2.9 ArcGIS Pro is now capable of connecting to a GPS device as discussed [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/device-location/gnss-and-location-devices.htm).*

If you are doing field mapping using ESRI software a superior way of doing that is using a program designed for fieldwork such as ArcGIS Collector which has recently been rebranded\superseded by [Field Maps](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-field-maps/overview).

This software is designed for in-field surveying and seamlessly integrates with the inbuilt GPS or a Bluetooth connected GPS. Someone in the field is going to simply want to capture points, lines and polygons and not be overwhelmed by the power of a desktop application. If what you are capturing is just information, rather than geometry look into using survey 123 instead. All of these integrate with ArcGIS Online for live real time mapping.

Comment: I believe field maps requires a named user account to arcgis online to download the data you upload(at additional cost). [Disclaimer was a field maps beta tester]

Comment: @Hornbydd, thank you for looking, but my team will be assisting military personnel who are going to map in the field which is a secured zone.
So, they are equipped with this Ice Age technology and hence we are bound to use it.

Comment: Ice age technology, love your description! Maybe a future opportunity for you to bring them into the Holocene? 

Comment: When you are a top tier/favored target of cyberattacks, you will understand these restrictions. It is not Ice Age, it is fully justified paranoia.