# Is it possible to connect using inbuild GPS in new machines with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, gps

We have recently got a set of new machines which are capable of tracking locations using a high-end inbuilt GPS/GNSS support.

The machine specifications are shared below:

- Microsoft Surface Pro 7+
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/surface/business/surface-pro-7-plus
- [Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS) driver architecture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gnss/gnss-driver-architecture)

I have an understanding that in earlier times when the machines used to have COM Ports, the legendary ArcMap has to be connected with the external GPS devices using these COM Ports, and with advancement, in machines, the virtual COMs played their roles. So, connecting an external device can be thought of.

Here my concern is quite different, and I would like to know if it's possible for us to connect the inbuilt GPS to show live location in ArcGIS Pro? If yes, then how should I get this to work. [Surface Pro LTE - routing the internal GPS to broadcast NMEA data to a virtual COM port](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-pro-lte-routing-the-internal-gps-to/550815c2-496e-4b6f-8f4f-27f31d2a38e3)

I was able to confirm that ArcGIS Collector shows my accurate location and is using the service, also the Microsoft maps which there by default in the machine are able to access my location.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/create-features-from-gnss-device-locations.htm) help page?

Comment: Thank you for pitching in @Hornbydd, this help doc is useful when we establish a successful connection with ArcGIS Pro, for me, the device is not listed under available devices:(

Comment: Maybe @Mapperz might have some insights. You have guided me with this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381879/arcmap-field-mapping-with-garmin-gps-connectivity-issue